# Ng-repeat with different group of radio buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I created a group of radio buttons and it didn't assign properly for each group. The button is not working when I click one of the button from one of the radio button group.

**Senario 1**

```
<div ng-repeat="m in meals">
  <label class="linked-radio"><span class="radio primary"><span></span>
    </span>{{ m.name }}
    <input type="radio" id="{{ m.id }}" ng-model="mealselected" ng-checked="isMealSelected(m.id);"/>
  </label>
</div>
```

> The radio button is not check when click

**Senario 2**

```
<div ng-repeat="m in meals">
  <input type="radio" id="{{ m.id }}" ng-model="mealselected"/>
    <label class="linked-radio">
        <span class="radio primary">
            <span></span>
        </span>{{ m.name }}
  </label>
</div>
```

> The radio button is checked but only the first one in each every group of radio buttons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`radiobutton` is grouped by `name` property, in the below code snippet, I just make 2 radiobutton groups. And for `label`, you should use `for` property and bind it with the relevant radiobutton's id.

```js
angular.module("app", [])
  .controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.mealselected = false;
    $scope.meals = [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: 'meal1'
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: 'meal2'
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: 'meal3'
      }
    ];
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <h1>Group1</h1>
  <div ng-repeat="m in meals">
    <label class="linked-radio" for="{{ m.id }}"><span class="radio primary"><span></span>
    </span>{{ m.name }}
    <input type="radio" id="{{ m.id }}" name="group1" ng-model="mealselected" />
  </label>
  </div>

  <h1>Group2</h1>
  <div ng-repeat="m in meals">
    <input type="radio" id="{{ m.id }} + 2" name="group2" ng-model="mealselected" />
    <label class="linked-radio" for="{{ m.id }} + 2">
        <span class="radio primary">
            <span></span>
        </span>{{ m.name }}
  </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `for` in label

Code :

```
<div ng-repeat="m in meals">
  <input type="radio" id="{{ m.id }}" name="radio_meal" ng-model="mealselected" value="{{m.id}}"/>
    <label for="{{ m.id }}" class="linked-radio">
        <span class="radio primary">
            <span></span>
        </span>{{ m.name }}
  </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `ng-repeat` in `<label>` tag instead of `<div>` tag. And use `ng-chage` instead of `ng-checked`. Like this:

> ```
> <div>
>   <label class="linked-radio" ng-repeat="m in meals" >
>   {{m.name}}
>     <input type="radio" ng-model="$parent.mealselected" ng-value="m.id"
>     ng-change="$parent.isMealSelected(m.id)"/>
>   </label> 
> </div>
> ```

`$parent` is used to access parent scope from child

Answer (score 0):

**DEMO**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.meals = [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: 'first'
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: 'second'
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: 'third'
      }
    ];
    
    $scope.mealselected = '';
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="m in meals">
  <label class="linked-radio" for="{{ m.id }}">{{ m.name }}
    <input type="radio" id="{{ m.id }}" name="meal" ng-model="mealselected"/>
  </label>
</div>
</div>
```